# Banker class long-term viability

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, class

I find home-brewing a banker class kind of fun. The gist is he/she can fast-track funds for the group, start a subscription ledger and have the local affluent commit funds for the next adventure. The group gets to use the funds to gear up before the adventure begins and just need to ensure they loot enough to pay dividends every now and then.

Other times the banker serves as a risk-smoother, allowing the party to take out an insurance policy for certain types of quests. This tends to embolden them and attempt things that they otherwise never would. We try to keep it within reason: mechanics haven't been abused yet. Plus, it's conceivable that some ventures will be too specific/nebulous to be insured or the backers cash out when it looks like it's opportune. The point is there is still a group-performance dimension to it all.

Intro aside, that may all be fine and dandy, but as many campaigns tend to demonstrate, the utility of purchasable advantages hits diminishing returns as time goes on. While moving wealth through time is a commendable contribution to the group, I fear his days of being useful are numbered. Even now when the adventure is in progress the banker can't do much aside from use his movement/actions to perform simple tasks like standing guard, translating languages or forming distractions.

To clarify, the player really enjoys role playing as this banker, so this question is more about troubleshooting around that and/or managing expectations.

### Question

How might a banker class maintain long-term viability as the campaign transitions from store-bought wares to items that are priced in quest/merit terms?

Comment: Is the banker supposed to be going on adventures with the party? This sounds more like a background/RP thing then an actual class. I've no idea what kind of utilty a banker should have in a dungeon.

Comment: We don't really do "write a homebrew" questions, and we can't answer your question without having some idea of what the class looks like. I've voted to close for "needs details", as the answer to your question depends entirely upon the sort of feature built into the class.

Comment: I for one would be very interested to hear about the mechanics of the class.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### You don't need a class for this, but you can use a background

Any friendly NPC who is willing to lend money to the PCs for a share of the spoils, payback with interest, handing over a specific item they are to obtain, etc. will do if all you want is to provide some more funds to the PCs early on.

If it is more about one of the players being interested in playing someone with such a banking bent, the best solution would be to develop this as a **character background** option.

The PHB states on page 45 about the characters:

> ADVENTURERS ARE EXTRAORDINARY PEOPLE, driven by a thirst for excitement into a **life that others would never dare lead**. They are heroes, compelled to explore the dark places of the world and take on the challenges that lesser women and men can’t stand against.

A banker's life seems to be not a fit at all for this lifestyle<sup>1</sup>. Nothing against that profession, but bankers sit safely in town and process loan applications. It is not going to be a role that can fill a useful spot to play in an adventuring party.

What you have in mind would be a much better fit for a *background*. The PHB introduces backgrounds like this:

> Every story has a beginning. Your character’s background reveals where you came from, how you became an adventurer, and **your place in the world**. Your fighter might have been a courageous knight or a grizzled soldier. Your wizard could have been a sage or an artisan. Your rogue might have gotten by as a guild thief or commanded audiences as a jester.

Backgrounds can come with connections and contacts. Take for instance the Criminal background:

> You have a reliable and trustworthy contact who acts as your liaison to a network of other criminals. You know how to get messages to and from your contact, even over great distances; specifically, you know the local messengers, corrupt caravan masters, and seedy sailors who can deliver messages for you.

In the same manner, the banker could have connections to his bank or the financial world, and as a feature be able to procure credit at preferable conditions, that the group otherwise would not have access to. And because a background still leaves the character the ability to level in their main class, it does not hurt at all that access to money may become less relevant over time.

The DMG has many pages of advise on how to tweak existing backgrounds or create new ones, starting on page 289, under **Creating a Background**.

---

<sup>1</sup> *If your world even has something like banks and credit; it's not out of place, in the real world advanced credit in banking started to develop in the [mid-middle ages](https://ehistory.osu.edu/articles/medieval-banking-twelfth-and-thirteenth-centuries).*

Comment: Nice answer, I was also going to suggest that this should be a background but you have covered the subject pretty extensively. There are a few “business related” backgrounds in *Acquisitions inc* that could serve as an inspiration, and perhaps the *Guild Merchant* from PHB too

Comment: The *Acquisitions Incorporated* also has player roles (called "company positions") that are separate from classes/backgrounds themselves, giving each party member a role that comes with certain responsibilities (in the running of the franchise) and grants certain proficiencies and starting equipment – as well as additional benefits that increase as the franchise advances in rank. Those mechanics might be useful/relevant here.

Comment: @V2Blast, Anna: I agree with both. I even looked at AqInc before writing the answer. I felt that this was a lot of overhead to bring in with the franchise and all just for the banker role, so steered clear of it. However, it might indeed be a great resource for this play group to take a closer look at, as it is emphasizing all kinds of related aspects, contract drafting etc. included.

Comment: Alric, Banker of the Wilderness enters a dragon's lair -- "In 12 months I can double the size of your hoard!", the the dragon's eyebrow lifts  "Interesting, Do go on..."